# Confused about Failed Facebook app review for user_friends permission

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-graph-api

We've submitted our app for review to get the Facebook user_friends permission. Our review was rejected with the following comments :

> While use case and screencast are approvable we could not reproduce
>   the permission due to errors on loading the app.

We've tested our app on PC, Android Studio and Android, no error on loading the app was found.

> Your app had errors that prevented us from fully testing it.
>   Please ensure that the APK provided is working correctly when run on
>   Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) or higher, as this is the version of Android
>   our team uses in review.

Inside Unity, we've set the "Minimum API Level" to Android 6.0, we've tested it in Android studio with Android 6.0, no error and everything works fine. We still got the same reply from the second Facebook review.

> Notes From Your Reviewer:
>   I've attached some screenshots that may help you understand my response
>   better. You can find them here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG6ic.jpg

We do not understand how this image could be helping us in any way.
Yes it looks like a ZIP of the APK we've provided, but why should this help us ?

We're just very confused with their review.

> "Confused about your review feedback? Ask a question"

We've tried that, no reply from them

Our app is built in Unity3d with the "Minimum API Level" set to Android 6.0.

We've also tried setting the "Target API Level" to Android 6.0 but we're getting this error :

> CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
>   C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.3.8f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.3.8f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.6.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"
>
> stderr[
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':processReleaseResources'.
>
>   > Android resource linking failed
>   >     Output:  error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.
>   >     error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored not found.
>   >     error: failed linking references.

Could anyone help us understand their comment and what's the problem with our app ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We did ask them, no reply for over 2 weeks. The review itself was rather quick, 1-2 days. I'm just hoping someone had a similar problem or understand their comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook finally replied with a new comment, explaining that they were not able to open the ZIP file of the app.

So after few more tries, uploading the .apk (not zipped) finally worked (the upload took about 5 to 10 min) and Facebook reviewed our app within the hour.

A direct dropbox link to the APK and a zipped APK did not work for us.